# Finite dimentional topological vector spaces

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

I was reading the functional analysis book of R.E. Edwards there is a theorem states that 
"  A topological vector spaces is finite dimentional if and only if there exists a precompact neighbourhood of zero " . 
the " only if " part is ok but  how can we tackle the converse part . Anyone any hints ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove the contrapositive: if $V$ is infinite dimensional then the unit ball is not compact in $V$.

To prove the hint you need to prove the following lemma due to Riesz:

> If $V$ is infinite dimensional, then for every proper subspace of $V$, say $X$,
>   there exists $x \not\in X$ such that $\|x\| = 1$ and $\|x-y\|> \frac{1}{2}$
>   for all $y \in X$.

Comment: Every topological vector space is normizable ?

Comment: I guess I was assuming normed vector spaces.

Comment: If you look at the dual of a normed vector space, which is a topological vector space, with the weak* topology, isn't the unit ball precompact?

Comment: I am very beginner to topological vector spaces. Though i used to be good in general topological spaces